# Storing user values using Firebase notification FCM token

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

Consider this use case: the users don't login or create a profile. However, some information (such as settings) should be saved on the database, for example:

```
/userSettings/{{UID}}
```

What should be used as the user's UID?

I have tried the `FCM token` since it would be unique for each user. However, this token is sometimes too long, and it seems that the access delay when there is a very long string in Firebase path is high.

I am considering using a [short hash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shorthash) of the FCM token on the client, but this might cause hash collision. So I'm asking what is the best practice for this?

Comment: FCM token is not a good idea, because they can change over time.  You really should be using Firebase Authentication for unique identification and data protection.  Anything else is not very secure for your app.

Comment: I don't care about security of the data. I just want each user to be able  to save some unimportant data. Also, I don't want  them to create a profile cause that's too much work for them.

Comment: Just use Firebase anonymous auth.  No need for the user to do anything.

Comment: Using anonymous auth, will the same user  get the same UID across different sessions of running the app?

Comment: Until something or someone clears the locally stored token.  At that point, you're getting a new FCM token anyway.